# Can I GROUP BY from last 100 records of table

Tags: mysql

I have thousands of records from my table, instead I want to count the total number of `location` with `GROUP BY` from the last 100 records of the table.

```
SELECT location, COUNT(*) as total FROM table GROUP BY location LIMIT 100
```

But the result returns the total counts of entire table.

Any ways to achieve it ?

Comment: Limit using subquery

Comment: @Kaushik could u show and example ?

Comment: `SELECT location, count(*) total FROM ( SELECT location FROM table LIMIT 100 ) s GROUP BY location;` similar to this

Comment: Data in sql is stored in unordered heaps how do you identify last 100 do you have an id field or date or some other column  which would help here?

Comment: Define 'last'.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first filter(using `sub query`) and then do the `Group By`

```
SELECT location, count(*) total FROM ( SELECT location FROM table LIMIT 100 ) s GROUP BY location;
```

Comment: Thanks. Just add `ORDER BY` to define the required last 100 rows